# Site needs "foosball" / "table-soccer" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Is there a reason there is no `foosball` or `table-soccer` tag in this site yet? I understand that this site is still in beta version, but I have questions related to foosball that I would like to ask. If anyone with high enough reputation sees this question, I think these tags [synonyms] would be useful for the site.

One complaint may be that it may not be considered a "sport", but there still are national foosball tournaments, so I think it would be pretty useful to add.

Comment: Ask a question about foosball, flag the question for moderators attention, and I will add the tag and the synonym.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and I can't think of other SE sites foosball would be on-topic for...so, it should work here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We do not and cannot proactively add tags to the site. Tags are only created when someone adds them to a question.

As edmastermind29 said, if you ask a question about a sport that does not yet have a tag and you don't have [enough reputation to create new tags](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), you can simply flag it for moderator attention and we'll edit it for you. If you don't even have enough reputation to flag for moderator attention... don't worry too much, someone will find it soon enough.