# Tags for lesser known sports

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, tags

I see there isn't a tag for some sports like darts, which probably wouldn't be as popular as football, NFL etc but there should really be tags if someone wants to ask a question related to that sport as it is quite a big sport in Britain.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that since you have more than 150 reputation points, you can [create tags](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). So if you ask a question about some particular sport, you can create a tag for that sport (if you consider such tag to be useful).

Comment: Also from what I have seen, I would say that the tag ([tag:international-sports]) is used for *various less-known sports*. (In cases when the particular sport does not seem to be important enough to have its own tag.)

Comment: @Martin I have seen `international-sports` used more as a catch-all when asking about multiple sports or identification of an unknown sport...not necessarily for "various less-known sports."

Comment: @edmastermind29 I meant for example questions like [this one](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/what-is-this-three-against-one-game-with-red-and-blue-balls) or [this one](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/870/identify-this-italian-sport), which are identify-this-sport question and they are tagged using this tag.

Comment: @Martin Which is identification of an unknown sport (to which I see your point of "various less-known sports," but had they known what the sport is, it would be tagged as such)...this isn't the majority usage however. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: Ok guess I should have read up on it a bit more, cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Popularity shouldn't be a precursor in creating tags. If someone wants to ask a question on darts, or a lesser-known sport, a flag is raised, a meta post (like yours) is made, or the tag is created.

The reason there isn't a tag for "darts" is because no question has been asked about darts. See [this](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/481/527) for more information:

> We do not and cannot proactively add tags to the site. Tags are only
>   created when someone adds them to a question.

Comment: FYI, there is now a tag for [darts](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/darts).