# Is Sumo wrestling on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, tags

Is Sumo wrestling questions on topic?

If it is on topic, please add a tag for that.

*I am not a fan of Sumo wrestling, but I work with a Japanese company and somewhere I read that Sumo is one of the popular sports in Japan.*

Comment: I don't see why not. Outside of this post, [this](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7185/really-fat-hockey-goalies#comment15052_7185) appears to be the only mention on Sports SE on sumo wrestling.

Comment: Yes, I checked.

Comment: To further ed's answer, you should know that if a tag gets only a single question for six months, it will get removed. So if you'd like the tag to stick around, ask a couple questions. Make sure they're good questions, though, don't ask a crappy question for the sake of keeping the tag around!

Comment: @corsiKa Well, unless somebody writes a tag-wiki. The feature request [Do not expire single-use tags that have a tag wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki) on meta.SE is marked as ([meta-tag:status-completed]).

Comment: The tag ([tag:sumo-wrestling]) has been created, including the [tag-excerpt](http://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/13171/revisions).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Please ask a question on sumo wrestling so that I can add the tag for you. We cannot proactively add tags for those that do not currently exist.

See [this answer](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/481) for more information.