# What do we do with newly created tags that are already covered by existing/related tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

It was brought to our attention in [The Clubhouse](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2433/conversation/tags-covered-by-existing-related-tags) regarding tags that are already covered by existing/related tags.

In this example, [penalty-card](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/penalty-card) has no usage guidance and was only used once. In reference to tagging [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/14711), [officiating](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/officiating) was suggested. I agreed and added that [penalty-card](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/penalty-card) would be covered under [officiating](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/officiating). That brought upon the topic of tag synonyms and tag removal.

Considering [penalty-card](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/penalty-card) is only used once, I suggested removal of the tag (which is slated for [automatic tag removal](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/631/is-sumo-wrestling-on-topic#comment1355_631) in its current state) and adding [officiating](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/officiating). However, this specificity (penalty card vs fouls vs flags vs penalty box vs disqualifications, etc) may be necessary.

**What do we do with newly created tags that are already covered by existing/related tags?** I believe this can be applied more generally than a case-by-case basis and along with the attention brought forth in The Clubhouse, I thought this question was appropriate to address.

Related discussion: [Grounds of Tag Creation](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312/grounds-of-tag-creation)